# Return where two columns match

Tags: excel, matching

Forgive me if this has been request before, any assistance is greatly appreciate.

I have the data below consisting of thousands of rows. I need to isolate rows only where the field1 and field2 columns match. is there a quick method of performing this in excel?

```
FileID1  FileID2 Hash
27468    27462   8BEA348CA9301F6459F8E8A2DD126D7C
29874    29843   EEFFBC24EAE3F4FD5ED5232993081A36
31150    1126    AE3675DC487DEF0F9C9FEC42B81B1438
**32330  32330   59D77968DB2FE6AFE42EEC21268F3D5A  **
33218    33211   9231697E3A859F0D2C4E39AFB1C4AFFE
33984    33980   3B20A501EB17BA2A6FA6A43D9A3D70BA
35275    35260   201D7B2CE5E1DB924CAEDC0F7DA93489
**35402  35402   726C1DEE00F5D17EAB39B3DD1AE4EC0E  **
35887    35883   176C07CD85BDD52449073310B9177977
36734    36657   2CDECE0B8C581D9E0F68B8BC3CEDAAB9
36924    36912   94BF549976E42D891F59A66C9972992E
```

BTW - I know that something like =IF(A1=B1,C1,"") but wanted something more refined where one does not have to copy the data, paste as text and then sort.

Comment: Why not just use `=If(A1=B1,"Yes","No")` then run that down the columns, the simply create a filter, that only shows "yes"?

Comment: this should work better, thanks

Comment: You could do this with the Advanced Filter.  And you can either filter in-place; or write the results to a different location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if `A column` for first ID and `B colum`n is second ID and `C column` is the hash values you can use in `D column` as an expression like that

```
=IF(A1=B1,1,0)
```

this gives a value 1 for equal values and gives 0 for the non-equal values

or like your example

```
=IF(A1=B1,"**","")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Dr Geek, pretty much the same as the above. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

To return the hashes where ID1 is equal to ID2, you can use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$12,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$12=$B$2:$B$12,ROW($C$2:$C$12)-ROW($C$2)+1),ROWS($C$2:C2)))
```

(enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>).

[image]

You can wrap `=IFERROR([formula above],"")` to hide the `#NUM!` errors).

You can make some tweaks to that, if you're not after just the hashes.  For instance, in D column, starting `D2`, you can use that *same* formula, just change the `Index()` columns at the start to be column A, and it'll return the IDs in column A that are duplicate too.